# How to query solr field for a substring

Tags: solr

My use case:
I have a single-valued field called cqpath. This is a textfield and has a values that look something like the following:

1. "/content/domain/en/path/to/some/page"
2. "/content/domain/en/path/to/another/page"
3. "/content/domain/en-us/path/to/some/page"
4. "/content/domain/en-us/path/to/another/page"

I wanted to form a query that would return me 1. and 2. I'd been trying along the lines of writing:

cqpath: "/content/domain/en"

which has been discovered to be erroneous, since it retrieves items 3. and 4. as well. Could any of you think of a way to write a query that returns only 1. and 2. and not 3. and 4.?

This is a normal textfield field-type. Really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using [StandardTokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer)? Can you post your `schema.xml` somewhere?

Comment: Could you copy it to a regular StrField and query with `field:/content/domain/en/*` ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Solr 4.0 you can use a regex query. You can find some useful examples [here](http://www.openjems.com/solr-regex-tutorial/).
In your case, you can get the results that you're looking for using something like:

```
cqpath:/.*content/domain/en.*/
```

Comment: i just tried that, and it doesn't seem to work. For some reason, the standard tokenizer seems to throw away the dash (-) and slashes (/) which is the root of the problem. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyways... My goal here is to mess around with tokenizer..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to match partial paths here with boundaries on path elements (slashes). The usual generic solution is to tokenize during index to generate all alternative completions and **not** tokenize during query. So, the field type declaration is not symmetric. There are examples of that in Solr distribution. And you would look at using something like (index-time only) [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#EdgeNGramFilterFactory) instead of much more expensive regex matching.

For your specific case, you may want to look at test[PathHierarchyTokenizer](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/path/PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory.html) which does that for you automatically.

And if your content were more like full URLs than just path, you could also be interested by a custom update request processor chain that includes [URLClassify URP](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/URLClassifyProcessorFactory.html). It is not very documented, but mentions [generating url parts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors#UpdateRequestProcessors-UpdateRequestProcessorFactories), which is what I think you would want.

Comment: PathHierarchyTokenizer is the answer... Thanks stranger (reddit gold) :)